# Why is state.map(foo => <>{foo}</>) not displaying anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

The first tsx code displays the state.map properly while the second displays nothing. Why? These 2 pieces of code are doing the same thing the same way, but still, one list is properly displayed and the other state.map has never rendered anything, despite many tweaks

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css'
const { useReducer } = require("react");
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'add': return [...state, action.item]
    case 'rm': return [...state.slice(0, action.index), ...state.slice(action.index + 1, state.length)]
    default: throw new Error();
  }
}
function Todo() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>TO DO</h1>
      <p>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'add', item: prompt('?') })}>+</button>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'rm', index: prompt('?') - 1 })}>-</button>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'rm', index: prompt('?') - 1 })}></button>
        <ol>{
          state.map((item) => (
            <>{item}</>
          ))}</ol>

      </p>

    </div>
  )
}
export default Todo
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import React from 'react';

const { useReducer } = require("react");
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'add': return [...state, action.item]
        case 'rm': return [...state.slice(0, action.index), ...state.slice(action.index + 1, state.length)]
        default: throw new Error();
    }
}
function Fees() {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, [])
    return (
        <body>
            <h1>Fees {state}</h1>
            <p>
                <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'add', item: prompt('Expense?') + prompt('Amount?') })}>+</button>
                <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'rm', index: prompt<number>('line number?') - 1 })}>-</button>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Expense
                            </th>
                        <th>
                            Amount
                            </th>
                        {state.map((item) => {
                            <td> {item}</td>
                        })}
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>Total</td></tr>
                </table>
            </p>
        </body>
    )
}
export default Fees
```

Comment: What action did you take to populate `state` in the first and second file?

Comment: The concept `useReducer` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: I filled it with the prompt in both of them

Comment: do you see a problem with my reducer? Because I do not

Comment: It is copy-pasted from the working to do list (first code)

Comment: Also, the Fees{state} is a debugger to ensure the state is correct at all times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, you need to return a component from map to make it rendered. The first example returns by default because you use paranthenses, while the second one does not. A bracket requires an explicit return statement.

Answer (score 2):

I have see function `prompt` is declare:

```
declare function prompt(message?: string, _default?: string): string | null;
```

You may remove type assign of return value , just and validation int later:

```
 <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'rm', index: prompt('line number?') - 1 })}>-</button>
```

Comment: Still does not work, I was not using the function remove